# How to detect type of expression?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, c++03

Sometimes, there are complicate expressions appear in the code. For example, intensive use of Boost library appeals these expressions. If I want to `typedef` type of these expression, I need to write out its type. Is there some way to know this type at compile time (***edit:*** or run-time)? Maybe, Boost offers appropriate functionality. I'd like to use it like to

```
#pragma message (...expression...)
```

***EDIT:*** If there is a problem with compile-time type detection, then run-time type detection fits too. For example, function like the following will suit

```
template <typename T> std::string detectExpressionType(T t);
```

Comment: c++11 added the decltype keyword but as you tag the question c++03…

Comment: Please people, stop menctioning `decltype()`. The question is tagged as C++03, so the question really is: ***I don't have C++11 decltype, sp how I can detect the type of an expression at compile time?***

Comment: @Manu343726 `decltype`'s at least a useful search term to find pre-C++11 non-Standard keywords and similar clumsy techniques that precipitated the Standardisation of `decltype`.

Answer (score 2):

Well in C++03 you can use template argument deduction:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T x)
{
    // Now you have the type of the expression.
}

int main()
{
    foo(1.0f * 2.0f);
}
```

You can't use this for your `#pragma message (...expression...)` case however because `#pragma` is a preprocessor directive. You can't really use any type information in the preprocessor stage.

Comment: Some libraries deliberately create an error that generates a message that they've found happens to document the problematic type on the compilers they're targeting - e.g. by trying to cast the value to some type yielding a "can't cast from type XYZ to <whatever>" message.  This approach won't allow a customised message and could be confusing, but it could perhaps be preceded by a `#pragma message` explaining more about the context....

Answer (score 1):

If you need it for debugging - let it fail. If runtime information is good enough you can demangle the type (below the demangle is for gcc).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cxxabi.h>

template <typename T> struct DebugType;
template <typename T>
inline void debug_type() {
    DebugType<T>();
}
template <typename T>
inline void debug_type(const T&) {
    DebugType<T>();
}

std::string demangle(const std::string& source_name)
{
    std::string result;
    size_t size = 4096;
    // __cxa_demangle may realloc()
    char* name = static_cast<char*>(malloc(size));
    try {
        int status;
        char* demangle = abi::__cxa_demangle(source_name.c_str(), name, &size, &status);
        if(demangle) result = demangle;
        else result = source_name;
    }
    catch(...) {}
    free(name);
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
inline void log_type() {
    std::clog << demangle(typeid(T).name()) << '\n';
}

template <typename T>
inline void log_type(const T&) {
    std::clog << demangle(typeid(T).name()) << '\n';
}

int main()  {
    // error: incomplete type ‘DebugType<int>’ used in nested name specifier
    // debug_type<int>();
    log_type<int>();

    // // error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct DebugType<std::basic_istream<char> >
    // debug_type(std::cin);
    log_type(std::cin);
    return 0;

}
```